# Erase drawing made on image view

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics

So, I am working on a virtual wall painting app.

I am able to draw some random lines by moving my finger on the image view(which has an image in it). Now I am trying to erase the drawings made on it without success as of yet.

I googled to find some solution and this line below came as full on recommended :-

```
CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),kCGBlendModeClear);
```

Using this drawing can be erased,but it also erases the image on which the drawing are done. Is there any way to prevent the image from getting erased ? only erase the drawing made on it?

Following is the code I am using to erase the drawings :-

In `touchesMoved:`-

```
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint previousPoint = [touch locationInView:self.upperImageView];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.upperImageView.frame.size);
[self.upperImageView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.upperImageView.frame.size.width, self.upperImageView.frame.size.height)];

CGContextSaveGState(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
CGContextSetShouldAntialias(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),YES);
CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), eraserCap);
CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 45.0);
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 1.0);
CGMutablePathRef pathB = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(pathB,nil,location.x,location.y);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathB,nil,previousPoint.x,previousPoint.y);
CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGBlendModeClear);
CGContextAddPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),pathB);
CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
upperImageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
CGContextRestoreGState(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
location = previousPoint;
```

and in `touchesEnded:`-

```
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint previousPoint = [touch locationInView:self.upperImageView];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.upperImageView.frame.size);
[self.upperImageView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.upperImageView.frame.size.width, self.upperImageView.frame.size.height)];
CGContextSaveGState(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
CGContextSetShouldAntialias(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), YES);
CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), eraserCap);
CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 5.0);
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1.0,1.0,1.0, 0.0);
CGMutablePathRef pathB = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(pathB, nil, location.x, location.y);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathB, nil, previousPoint.x, previousPoint.y);
CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGBlendModeClear);
CGContextAddPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),pathB);
CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
self.upperImageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
// CGContextRestoreGState(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
previousPoint = location;
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong ? Please guide me in the right direction here, any help will be truly appreciated.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26911271/how-to-undo-a-line-stroke-ios/26988840#26988840) might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use different views for your image and drawings. 
Or keep drawn paths in the array and delete each path separately.

Comment: the erasing should happen as the user will drag his finger over the drawings .. how would array help here ?

Comment: @Shailesh It wouldn't. That way **would** be helpful for an undo stack.

Answer (score 0):

Move all of your drawing to a separate `UIView` that overlays the `UIImageView`. That way, when you go to "clear" the contents, the original `UIImageView` is still completely intact underneath.

Something like this will get you set up:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear {
    // Assumes you add a property of type UIView
    self.drawingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.upperImageView.bounds];
    [self.upperImageView addSubview:drawingView];

}
```

Then, your drawing code needs to only change to this (notice that you won't need to redraw the image any more):

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint previousPoint = [touch locationInView:self.drawingView];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.drawingView.frame.size);
    CGContextSaveGState(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    CGContextSetShouldAntialias(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),YES);
    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), eraserCap);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 45.0);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 1.0);
    CGMutablePathRef pathB = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(pathB,nil,location.x,location.y);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathB,nil,previousPoint.x,previousPoint.y);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGBlendModeClear);
    CGContextAddPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),pathB);
    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    upperImageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    CGContextRestoreGState(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    location = previousPoint;
}
```

Make similar changes in the `touchesEnded:` method.

Comment: Yes .. thats quite a workaround ! but since I am trying to make a virtual wall painting .. I would require "undo" & "redo" (array would come handy here). If I am to maintain a separate view,how can i make a undo/redo stack ?

Comment: Also, I would need to implement a "colour fill" functionality too.. like a user touches anywhere on the image and it colours same coloured  areas ..I am not sure if using the overlay view will be useful ??

Comment: @Shailesh The undo/redo stack can be done whether you do the separate view or not. I'm not advanced enough in graphics to know how to do a color fill. Maybe, if you do a check to see if a particular pixel has been made clear, you replace it with the original color value? I think you've got a big task ahead of you.